# How to drag and drop image in the same block with the help of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing one problem that I want to drag image and drop in between two images or swap two images with the help of javascript. But I am unable to do this. As in the below code there is a div of background color in that while I am clicking below icons they will move on that div one by one. But the next thing I have to do is that I have to drag and drop the images that are going to that div or even swap them or placed a image in between the two. I am unable to does that task. Can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

This is my code :

```js
function changeHome() {
  document.getElementById('color').style.backgroundColor = "coral";
}

function changeGray() {
  document.getElementById('color').style.backgroundColor = "gray";
}

function changeRed() {
  document.getElementById('color').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function changeGreen() {
  document.getElementById('color').style.backgroundColor = "green";
}

function changeBlue() {
  document.getElementById('color').style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.image').click(function() {
    var srcimg = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#color').append("<img src=" + srcimg + "  width='70' height='70'>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br/>
<div class="container">
  <h1 align="center"><u> JavaScript Simple learning </u></h1>
  <h3 align="center"> Use of JavaScript to drag and drop icons in Background image </h3>
  <br/> <br/>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div id="color">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <button onclick="changeHome()"> Home Color  </button> <br/><br/><br/>
    <button onclick="changeGray()"> Click for Gray </button> <br/><br/>
    <button onclick="changeRed()"> Click for Red </button> <br/><br/>
    <button onclick="changeGreen()"> Click for Green </button> <br/><br/>
    <button onclick="changeBlue()"> Click for Blue </button> <br/><br/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h2><u> List of Icons </u></h2>
  <img class="image" src="images/fb.jpeg" width="70" height="70" />
  <img class="image" src="images/twitter.jpeg" width="70" height="70" />
  <img class="image" src="images/linkedin.jpeg" width="70" height="70" />
  <img class="image" src="images/gmail.jpeg" width="70" height="70" />
  <img class="image" src="images/instagram.jpeg" width="70" height="70" />
  <img class="image" src="images/whatsapp.jpeg" width="70" height="70" />
  <img class="image" src="images/telegram.jpeg" width="70" height="70" />
</div>
```

Comment: You can do this with the help of HTML5 (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp) or can use interactjs.io.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that one but in that the image will disappear after dragging. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two separate methods for drop.One is for appending an image and another is for replacing an image.You can try the following :

**SCRIPT Content**

```
<script>
        function changeHome() {
            document.getElementById('color').style.backgroundColor = "coral";
        }

        function changeGray() {
            document.getElementById('color').style.backgroundColor = "gray";
        }

        function changeRed() {
            document.getElementById('color').style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }

        function changeGreen() {
            document.getElementById('color').style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }

        function changeBlue() {
            document.getElementById('color').style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.image').click(function () {
                var srcimg = $(this).attr('src');
                var imgid = $(this).attr('id');
                console.log($(this));
                $('#color').append('<div ondrop="drop(event)"  ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="float:left;display:block;height:50px;width:50px"><img id=' + imgid + "1" + ' src=' + srcimg + ' draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="70" height="70">');
            });
        });

        function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("src", ev.target.id);
        }

        function drop(ev,ui) {
            console.log("evvv" + ev.srcElement);
            console.log($(this).parent('div'));
            ev.preventDefault();
            var src = document.getElementById(ev.dataTransfer.getData("src"));
            var srcParent = src.parentNode;
            if (srcParent.parentNode.id == "div1")
            {
                var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("src");
                ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
            }
            else
            {
                var tgt = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;

                ev.currentTarget.replaceChild(src, tgt);
                srcParent.appendChild(tgt);
            }

        }
        function drop1(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("src");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
    </script>
```

**HTML Content**

```
    <div class="container">
        <h1 align="center"><u> JavaScript Simple learning </u></h1>
        <h3 align="center"> Use of JavaScript to drag and drop icons in Background image </h3>
        <br /> <br />
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div id="color" style="height:100px" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" >
            </div>
        </div><br /><br />
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button onclick="changeHome()"> Home Color  </button> <br /><br /><br />
            <button onclick="changeGray()"> Click for Gray </button> <br /><br />
            <button onclick="changeRed()"> Click for Red </button> <br /><br />
            <button onclick="changeGreen()"> Click for Green </button> <br /><br />
            <button onclick="changeBlue()"> Click for Blue </button> <br /><br />
        </div>

</div>
<div class="container" id="div1">
    <h2><u> List of Icons </u></h2>
    <div style="float:left;display:block">
        <img class="image" id="img1" src="Images/natural.jpg" width="70" height="70" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;display:block">
        <img class="image" id="img2" src="Images/nature2.jpg" width="70" height="70" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
        </div>
    <div style="float:left;display:block">
        <img class="image" id="img3" src="Images/sunset.jpg" width="70" height="70" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
        </div>
    <div style="float:left;display:block">
        <img class="image" id="img4" src="Images/dp1.jpg" width="70" height="70" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
        </div>
    <div style="float:left;display:block">
        <img class="image" id="img5" src="Images/dp2.jpg" width="70" height="70" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
        </div>
    <div style="float:left;display:block">
        <img class="image" id="img6" src="Images/guitar.jpg" width="70" height="70" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
        </div>
    <div style="float:left;display:block">
        <img class="image" id="img7" src="Images/images.jpg" width="70" height="70" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: One more doubt how can I remove single photo on double click event. I am trying but not succeeded till now.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove single photo on double click event by using the following function:

**SCRIPT Content**

```
function ImageDel(elem)
        {

            elem.parentElement.remove();  //to remove an parent div of the image
            elem.remove();  //to remove the image
        }
```

**HTML Content**

```
  <img ondblclick="ImageDel(this)" width="70" height="70">
```